# Hide/show chart.js charts

Tags: javascript, html, django, chart.js

I have this code snippet down below which basically alternates between 3 canvases, the user should chose which chart to display, and it's working fine as you can see (try to change between select values from line to bar to radar and it will display chosen chart and hide others )
I would like to do a little modification, when the page loads I want only 1 chart to be display ( the line chart), and then the same thing should be happening, if u want to change to another type of chart then using the select box do so.
The problem is , when I add "hidden" to the bar and radar charts, the whole thing stops working and by choosing from the select box it doesn't work, any idea how to show only the line chart at the beginning without harming the whole process I did?
thank you

```js
    function updateChartType() {
    var all_types = ["turn_over_line", "turn_over_bar", "turn_over_radar"];
    var current_shown =document.getElementById("chartType").value;

      for( var i = 0; i < all_types.length; i++) {

          if (all_types[i] != current_shown) {
              if (document.getElementById(all_types[i]).style.display!="none")
              {
              document.getElementById(all_types[i]).style.display="none";
          }
          }
          else {
              if (document.getElementById(all_types[i]).style.display!="block")
              {
              document.getElementById(all_types[i]).style.display="block";

          }}
      }

}
```

```css
.cann {
  border: 3px solid darkgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
    width: 650px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 3em;


}
```

```html
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- semantic UI -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.14/semantic.min.css">
    <!--Chart js-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.2.1"> </script>    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css" integrity="sha256-aa0xaJgmK/X74WM224KMQeNQC2xYKwlAt08oZqjeF0E=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
// Turn over line chart
$(document).ready(function (){
        var ctx = document.getElementById('turn_over_line');
         var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
  data: {
     labels: [1500,1600,1700,1750,1800,1850,1900,1950,1999,2050],
    datasets: [{ 
        data: [86,114,106,106,107,111,133,221,783,2478],
        label: "Africa",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [282,350,411,502,635,809,947,1402,3700,5267],
        label: "Asia",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [168,170,178,190,203,276,408,547,675,734],
        label: "Europe",
        borderColor: "#3cba9f",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [40,20,10,16,24,38,74,167,508,784],
        label: "Latin America",
        borderColor: "#e8c3b9",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [6,3,2,2,7,26,82,172,312,433],
        label: "North America",
        borderColor: "#c45850",
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
       animation: {
           duration : 700,
               easing : 'easeInOutSine',
    },
 title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Turn over per site'
      },
       responsive : false,
  }
} );


     });
     
     // Turn over bar chart
$(document).ready(function (){
        var ctx = document.getElementById('turn_over_bar');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

   "type": "bar",
  "data": {
    labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Population (millions)",
          backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
          data: [2478,5267,734,784,433]
        }
      ]
    },
  "options": {
        title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Turn over per site'
      },
       responsive : false,
    "scales": {
      "yAxes": [{
        "id": "stacked_testY",
        "type": 'linear',
        "position": "left",
        "stacked": true,
        "display": true
      }],
      "xAxes": [{
        "position": "bottom",
        "stacked": true,
        "display": true
      }]
    }
  }
} );
     });

//Turn over radar
$(document).ready(function (){
var ctx = document.getElementById('turn_over_radar');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
"type": "radar",
"data": {
   labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "1950",
          fill: true,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,0.2)",
          borderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
          pointBorderColor: "#fff",
          pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
          data: [8.77,55.61,21.69,6.62,6.82]
        }, {
          label: "2050",
          fill: true,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
          borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
          pointBorderColor: "#fff",
          pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
          pointBorderColor: "#fff",
          data: [25.48,54.16,7.61,8.06,4.45]
        }
      ]
    },
  "options": {
        title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Turn over per site'
      },
       responsive : false,

  }
} );
});


</script>
 <div>
    <select class="chart_types" name="chartType" id="chartType" onchange="updateChartType()">
      <option value="turn_over_line">Line</option>
      <option value="turn_over_bar">Bar</option>
      <option value="turn_over_radar">Radar</option>
    </select>
<br><br>
<canvas id="turn_over_line" class="cann"></canvas>
<canvas id="turn_over_bar" class="cann" >  </canvas>
<canvas id="turn_over_radar" class="cann" >  </canvas>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code as follows:

- Set the canvas with the inline style `display:none;`.
- Create individual functions for each chart.
- Set only 1 `.ready` function - which will call the created functions mentioned in the previous step.
- Create a function for handle the selected value in the `select` HTML element; with the selected value, set which chart to show.

This is the modified code:

```js
// Load charts: 
$(document).ready(function() {
  load_radar_chart();
  load_bar_chart();
  load_line_chart();
});

/*
   Load line-type chart: 
*/
function load_line_chart() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('turn_over_line');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: [1500, 1600, 1700, 1750, 1800, 1850, 1900, 1950, 1999, 2050],
      datasets: [{
        data: [86, 114, 106, 106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 783, 2478],
        label: "Africa",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      }, {
        data: [282, 350, 411, 502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3700, 5267],
        label: "Asia",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        fill: false
      }, {
        data: [168, 170, 178, 190, 203, 276, 408, 547, 675, 734],
        label: "Europe",
        borderColor: "#3cba9f",
        fill: false
      }, {
        data: [40, 20, 10, 16, 24, 38, 74, 167, 508, 784],
        label: "Latin America",
        borderColor: "#e8c3b9",
        fill: false
      }, {
        data: [6, 3, 2, 2, 7, 26, 82, 172, 312, 433],
        label: "North America",
        borderColor: "#c45850",
        fill: false
      }]
    },
    options: {
      animation: {
        duration: 700,
        easing: 'easeInOutSine',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Turn over per site'
      },
      responsive: false,
    }
  });
}

/*
   Load radar-type chart: 
*/
function load_radar_chart() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('turn_over_radar');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    "type": "radar",
    "data": {
      labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "1950",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,0.2)",
        borderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
        pointBorderColor: "#fff",
        pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
        data: [8.77, 55.61, 21.69, 6.62, 6.82]
      }, {
        label: "2050",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
        borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
        pointBorderColor: "#fff",
        pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
        pointBorderColor: "#fff",
        data: [25.48, 54.16, 7.61, 8.06, 4.45]
      }]
    },
    "options": {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Turn over per site'
      },
      responsive: false,

    }
  });
}


/*
   Load bar-type chart: 
*/
function load_bar_chart() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('turn_over_bar');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    "type": "bar",
    "data": {
      labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Population (millions)",
        backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2", "#3cba9f", "#e8c3b9", "#c45850"],
        data: [2478, 5267, 734, 784, 433]
      }]
    },
    "options": {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Turn over per site'
      },
      responsive: false,
      "scales": {
        "yAxes": [{
          "id": "stacked_testY",
          "type": 'linear',
          "position": "left",
          "stacked": true,
          "display": true
        }],
        "xAxes": [{
          "position": "bottom",
          "stacked": true,
          "display": true
        }]
      }
    }
  });
}

/*
   Hide or shown chart - see value of "selected_chart_id" parameter: 
*/
function updateChartType(selected_chart_id) {

  var all_types = ["turn_over_line", "turn_over_bar", "turn_over_radar"];

  for (var i = 0; i < all_types.length; i++) {
    if (all_types[i] == selected_chart_id) {
      document.getElementById(all_types[i]).style.display = "";
    } else {
      document.getElementById(all_types[i]).style.display = "none";
    }
  }

}
```

```css
.cann {
  border: 3px solid darkgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  width: 650px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 3em;
}
```

```html
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- semantic UI -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.14/semantic.min.css">
<!--Chart js-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.2.1">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css" integrity="sha256-aa0xaJgmK/X74WM224KMQeNQC2xYKwlAt08oZqjeF0E=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select class="chart_types" name="chartType" id="chartType" onchange="updateChartType(this.value)">
    <option value="turn_over_line">Line</option>
    <option value="turn_over_bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="turn_over_radar">Radar</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <canvas id="turn_over_line" class="cann"></canvas>
  <canvas id="turn_over_bar" class="cann" style="display:none;">  </canvas>
  <canvas id="turn_over_radar" class="cann" style="display:none;">  </canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting to do the same thing, of course, it wouldn't work because I was confused between CSS's style = none and HTML's "hidden" attribute.
To accomplish what I am looking for I created this javascript function :

```
   function hide_charts() {
  document.getElementById("turn_over_bar").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("turn_over_radar").style.display="none";

}
```

And called it on the load of my page by adding to my HTML template :

```
<body onload="hide_charts()">
```